# Assigning extension methods to a delegate using ternary statements

Tags: c#, methods, extension-methods, ternary

## Assumptions

Let's assume we have an interface, and the following extension methods defined for said interface (*their implementations aren't important*)

```
public interface IPerson;

public class IPersonExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool SayHello(this IPerson talker, IPerson listener);
    public static bool SayGoodbye(this IPerson talker, IPerson listener);
}
```

## Problem

We know that both extension methods are fundamentally the same, in that they accept 2 parameters of type `IPerson`, and return `bool`. Now, let's assume we want to assign 1 of the extension methods to a delegate of type `Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool>` we could use:

```
Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool> whatShouldWeSay;
if (sayHello)
{
    whatShouldWeSay = IPersonExtensionMethods.SayHello;
}
else
{
    whatShouldWeSay = IPersonExtensionMethods.SayGoodbye;
}
```

However if we turn the `if` statement into shorthand, as follows:

```
Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool> whatShouldWeSay = (sayHello)
    ? IPersonExtensionMethods.SayHello
    : IPersonExtensionMethods.SayGoodbye;
```

We get the compilation error message:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'method.group' and 'method.group'

## Question

Why is this error occurring? Is it due to the nature of the delegate being an extension method; or is it due to how the short-hand `if` statement is determined the result type? Or is it something different entirely?

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because in a ternary statement both results (true and false) need to be the same type. This same thing would happen with regular methods as well, not just extension methods. You will need to cast them to the target type:

```
Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool> whatShouldWeSay = (sayHello) 
    ? (Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool>)IPersonExtensionMethods.SayHello
    : (Func<IPerson, IPerson, bool>)IPersonExtensionMethods.SayGoodbye;
```

I've experienced this a bit when using null in a ternary statement, it feels very strange to see `null` cast as some nullable type. This can be shown in a simpler way here:

```
// Doesn't compile
int? a = true ? 10 : null;

// Compiles
int? a = true ? 10 : (int?)null;
```

We get the following compiler error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tyriar, but this is where the confusion lays, both results are the same, regardless of the cast, surely?

Comment: Are they the same though? You're returning two *different* methods, they are only boxed in the same `Func` type after the assignment.

Comment: Interestingly; by casting only the second result, i.e. `SayGoodbye`, it compiles. Will casting one define the latter, or in this case, the prior?

Comment: Both true and false results just need to return the same type.